# Matching fixed-length word with known order of unknown characters

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to kind of brute force a cipher text where I don't know what any of the characters are, but I do know the language, the length of each word and the position of all the characters.

One of the words in the text is "avarrm", so I was hoping I could loop through a dictionary of words and try to match only the ones where the character in the first position is the same as the one in the third position, and the character in the 4th position is the same as the one in the 5th position, with the remaining characters not being either of those two characters or the same as each other.

It sounds like a job for a regex, but I have absolutely no idea how I would go about writing it. Is this doable, and if so, how? Or should I forget about regex and do it with a bunch of ifs?

Comment: When we talk about regex, please specify the flavor or the language you're using :)

Comment: Python would be preferable.

Comment: An alternative approach would be to normalize the dictionary words changing first char to `a`, second char to `b` if different from first else `a`, and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be the one required:

```
^(.).\1(.)\2((?!(\1|\2)).)*$
```

`(.).\1(.)\2` matches a character followed by a character followed by one same as the first followed by two identical characters.

`((?!(\1|\2)).)*` matches zero or more characters which is neither the first character nor the fourth.

Is this your requirement?

**EDIT**

This one would ensure that the last part won't have repeating characters:

```
^(.).\1(.)\2((?!(.).*\4)(?!(\1|\2)).)*$
```

For the second character not to be a repeated one, use:

```
^(.)((?!\1).)\1((?!(\1|\2)).)\3((?!(.).*\6)(?!(\1|\2|\3)).)*$
```

Comment: Let me give you an example of a string that would match: `abasso`. With this regex, it doesn't seem to match.

Comment: @TommyBrunn it is matching when i tested.

Comment: @TommyBrunn For working in python, you may have to do required escaping and flagging. I am new to python

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but this looks right to me, yet it doesn't match: http://pastie.org/7123279

Comment: @TommyBrunn I tried it here http://ksamuel.pythonanywhere.com/ and it worked with re.match

Comment: @TommyBrunn There, the code generated is `re.match(ur'''^(.).\1(.)\2((?!(.).*\4)(?!(\1|\2)).)*$''', u'''abasso''')`. I don't know the purpose of the `'`s. But it seems working

Answer (score 0):

Another approach could be to transform the strings to number sequences:

```
str1 = 'avarrm'
str2 = 'lylbbn'

def num_sequence(str_arg):
    return [dict(zip(str_arg, range(len(str_arg))))[n] for n in str_arg]

print num_sequence(str1), num_sequence(str2)
```

which would output

[0, 3, 2, 3, 5, 5]
[0, 3, 2, 3, 5, 5]

Since the lists are equal, 'lylbbn' is a solution candidate.